# SLURM: How to determine maximum --cpus-per-task and --mem-per-cpu?

Tags: slurm

How can I determine the optimum/maximum number of CPUs per task when running a job? Is there a way to display the total available memory on a given CPU as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `sinfo` to find maximum CPU/memory per node. To quote from [here](http://www.ceci-hpc.be/slurm_faq.html#Q07):

```
$ sinfo -o "%15N %10c %10m  %25f %10G"
NODELIST        CPUS       MEMORY      FEATURES                  GRES      
mback[01-02]    8          31860+      Opteron,875,InfiniBand    (null)    
mback[03-04]    4          31482+      Opteron,852,InfiniBand    (null)    
mback05         8          64559       Opteron,2356              (null)    
mback06         16         64052       Opteron,885               (null)    
mback07         8          24150       Xeon,X5550                TeslaC1060
mback[08-19]    8          24151       Xeon,L5520,InfiniBand     (null)    
mback[20-32,34] 8          16077       Xeon,L5420                (null)
```

I'm not sure what you mean by optimum CPU "per task". This depends on the specific program you are attempting to run.